# webkitbrowser load shared file on a network

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, webkit

I want to load an HTML file that is shared in the network with webkitbrowser in winform C#.

For example a file url in a browser is:

```
file:///10.10.10.10/files/index.html
```

I also tried this in webkitbroeser:

```
file://///10.10.10.10//files//index.html
```

Webkitbrowser doesn't load HTML file. In local there is no problem. I use this url:

```
file:///c://index.html
```

WinAPP, C#, Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

You were close.  Instead of 2 slashes, just use 1:

```
webKitBrowser1.Navigate("file:///c:/my/local/path/test.html");
```